# Надо сохранить информацию о том сколько раз пользователь подсмотрел ответ

Tags: java, android

Есть небольшое приложение: надо хранить информацию о том сколько раз был подсмотрен ответ(ответ находится во второй Активити, при возвращении счетчик сбивается). Подскажите, как решить этот вопрос. Не судите строго, так как я новичок в этом деле.

Comment: можно класс сделать, где будет переменная с этим значением, при каждом заходе к переменной будет кидаться +1

Comment: вам нужны `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Хранить пока приложение живет в памяти или должна пережить рестарты?

Comment: пережить рестарты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну что бы счетчик сохранялся и после рестартов приложения, я бы использовал **SharedPreferences**

это для того что бы сохранить значение:

```
public void saveCount(int count){
    SharedPreferences  sPref = getSharedPreferences("My Count", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putInt("COUNT", count);
    ed.commit();
}
```

ну а это для того что бы вытащить сохраненое значение:

```
public int loadCount() {
    SharedPreferences sPref= getSharedPreferences("My Count", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPref.getInt("COUNT", -1);
}
```